# BIND9: Is possible to point another ip address for main domain?

Tags: bind

This is my zone file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 10800      ; 3 hours
example.com           IN SOA  ns1.example.com. email.example.com. (
                                25         ; serial
                                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.example.com.
                        NS      ns2.example.com.
                        A       192.0.2.1
                        MX      10 mail.example.com.
$ORIGIN example.com.
ftp                     CNAME   example.com.
mail                    A       192.0.2.1
ns1                     A       192.0.2.1
ns2                     A       192.0.2.1
www                     CNAME   example.com.
```

Is it possible `ns1.example.com` be 192.0.2.1 but `example.com` be 192.0.2.2 ? (without using another DNS server on 192.0.2.2)
How I can do that?

Comment: Please do not use IP addresses such as `2.2.2.2` or even worse `1.1.1.1` in examples. They are real, they exist,and have global public widely known service attached to them. I edited your post in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `example.com. IN A` can certainly point to any IP address other than the IP addresses of your *authoritative name servers*. However, you should still have at least two different name servers on separate networks. This comes from IANA's [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements):

> **Minimum number of name servers**
>
> There must be at least two NS records listed in a delegation, and the
>   hosts must not resolve to the same IP address.
>
> **Network diversity**
>
> The name servers must be in at least two topologically separate
>   networks. A network is defined as an origin autonomous system in the
>   BGP routing table. The requirement is assessed through inspection of
>   views of the BGP routing table.